# Question about hatch function using pyautocad

Tags: python, autocad

I encounter a question about the Hatch function of pyautocad (python 3.9.7).

Here is my code.

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint, aDouble
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
acad.prompt('Echo\n')

pattern_type = 0
pattern_name = "ANSI31"
hatchObj = acad.model.AddHatch(pattern_type, pattern_name, True)
hatchObj.LinetypeScale = 6
hatchObj.PatternScale = 2
    
center = APoint(200, 0)
radius = 150
circle1 = acad.model.AddCircle(center, radius)

hatchObj.AppendOuterLoop(circle1)
```

I tried to hatch a circle in AutoCAD by using pyautocad commands.

But I got the COMError :

COMError: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', ('Invalid object array', 'AutoCAD.Application', 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2021\HELP\OLE_ERR.CHM', -2145320837, None))

Does anyone encounter the same question but get solutions?

Comment: I think you may need to pass a list to `.AppendOuterLoop()`, rather than a single shape object.

Comment: Yes, it needs to input a list of drawing objects, but did not work when I using the hatch function from "pyautocad".
Therefore, I used win32com to manipulate the AutoCAD.

Comment: And Here is the code.

`import math, win32com.client, pythoncom`
`acadwin32 = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")`
`acadmodel = acadwin32.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace `
`cir = acadmodel.AddArc(APointWin32(0,0, 0), 300, 0, math.pi)`
`cir2 = acadmodel.AddArc(APointWin32(0,0, 0), 300, math.pi, 2 * math.pi)`
`cirout = []`
`cirout.append(cir)`
`cirout.append(cir2)`
`cirout = AVariantWin32(cirout)`
`hatchObj = acadmodel.AddHatch(0, 'SOLID', True)`
`hatchObj.AppendouterLoop((cirout))`